# merge statement when not matched by source then insert to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created two tables `customersrc` and `customertemp` with the columns:

**customertemp**

```
ID  name    age addr    cityid  isactive
34  Gi      24  Chennai     1   1
```

**customersrc**

```
CustomerId  CustomerName    CustomerAge CustomerAddress
1            Gi               24    madurai
2            Pa               23    Tirupur
3            MI               27    Tirupur
```

Now I need to insert pa and mi data value to the temp table bcz it is not matched with the rows of `customertemp`. And the row gi data will be updated which was matched.

I used the following `MERGE` statement

```
DECLARE @cityid INT SET @cityid=1

MERGE Temp.dbo.customersrc as src_customer
USING ( SELECT CustomerName,CustomerAge,CustomerAddress FROM customertemp) as temp_customer
ON src_customer.name=temp_customer.CustomerName 
    AND
    src_customer.cityid=@cityid
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET 
                src_customer.age=temp_customer.CustomerAge,
                src_customer.addr=temp_customer.CustomerAddress,
                src_customer.isactive=1

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
     UPDATE SET src_customer.isactive=0 ;  -- here i need the insert statement to insert in another table
```

Questions:

1. is it possible to write insert statement inside the when not matched by source query?
2. if it is not possible then how to achieve this using `merge`?
3. in a simple set theory I need to put the customersrc(table_B)-customertemp (table_A). B-A value into the another or temp table.

Comment: This is an unusual requirement. Why do you want to insert to another table? Will you insert that data later into customersrc?

Comment: no to show the user who are not in the customertemp table.

Answer (score 2):

One of the main usages of the MERGE statement is to perform so called "UPSERTS" (Update matching records, insert new records), so it is definitely possible to do what you want. Just add the following to the last part of your MERGE statement:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (name, age, addr, cityid, isactive)
    VALUES (CustomerName, CustomerAge, CustomerAddress, @cityid, 1)
```

If you also need to insert data into a 3rd table, depending on whether rows are updated or inserted, you can use the OUTPUT clause of the merge statement. Check out the documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: thanks for your faster reply. in a scenario, merge when matched has update operation (this updation for all the rows in table) and merge when not matched by source has some update operation (this updation is for some rows in same table). is it possible to get the only updated data of when not matched by source in output clause.

Comment: You can use the special $action column to determine what operation was performed for each record in the output.

Comment: that $action column shows all the updated query value. i.e both when matched update condition values and when not matched by source update condition value. both operations are used in the same merge statement.

Comment: Then make sure to also output the `isactive` column. That way, all output records where `$action = 'UPDATE' AND isactive = 0` are records from the WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE condition.

Answer (score 0):

> Me: Why do you want to insert to another table?
>
> You: To show the user who are not in the customertemp table.

So your requirement is not to insert into another table. Your requirement is to get the missing users.

You could do that with a dummy `UPDATE` (`SET SomeCol = SomeCol`) and `OUTPUT`. But that is a hack that I would try to avoid.

It is probably easier to do this in two statements. Here's how you'd get the missing rows:

```
SELECT temp_customer.*
FROM (SELECT CustomerName,CustomerAge,CustomerAddress FROM customertemp) as temp_customer
LEFT JOIN customersrc ON src_customer.name=temp_customer.CustomerName AND src_customer.cityid=@cityid
WHERE customersrc.cityid IS NULL
```